# Check cURL output PHP

Tags: php, curl

i'm trying to check the output of a cURL.

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://blablabla.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $curlresult=curl_exec ($ch);
      curl_close ($ch);



    if ($curlresult == "OK") {
        $result = "The curl action was succeeded! (OUTPUT of curl is: ".$curlresult.")";
    } else {
        $result = "The curl action has FAILED! (OUTPUT of curl is: ".$curlresult.")";
    }

echo $result;

?>
```

The URL (https://blablabla.com) is a URL that just displays OK.
So, using the code, I would expect to see

> "The curl action was succeeded! (OUTPUT of curl is: OK)"

But, what I do get is:

> The curl action has FAILED! (OUTPUT of curl is: OK )

I guess i'm making some stupid mistake. How can I check if https://blablabla.com contains "OK"?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a vardump of $curlresult

Comment: Id guess there is some extra output before the "OK". Perhaps a newline.

Comment: you should check the HTTP status code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be getting extra white spaces before or after the OK or other characters.

I suggest doing what the people above suggested by testing what is exactly inside the array with `var_dump($curlresult);` or `print_r($curlresult);`

But alternatively you could instead of matching that $curlresult equals only "OK", you could test if $curlresult contains "OK" inside of it.

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://blablabla.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $curlresult=curl_exec ($ch);
      curl_close ($ch);



    if (preg_match("/OK/i", $curlresult)) {
        $result = "The curl action was succeeded! (OUTPUT of curl is: ".$curlresult.")";
    } else {
        $result = "The curl action has FAILED! (OUTPUT of curl is: ".$curlresult.")";
    }

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Indeed, using var_dump, I found out there was a space after OK :). Stupid I didn't see that..

Using (preg_match("/OK/i", $curlresult)) I fixed the problem. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Glad you found it out! If this helped you our, would you be so kind as to mark this as the correct answer. :) Thanks Mitch!

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($info);
```

gives you info on http status code returned and connect time etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `var_dump($curlresult);` to see what you're really getting, otherwise i think there may be a problem with using SSL (HTTPS), to quick fix this (accept any server certificate):

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://blablabla.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $curlresult=curl_exec ($ch);
     curl_close ($ch);



    if ($curlresult == "OK") {
        $result = "The curl action was succeeded! (OUTPUT of curl is: ".$curlresult.")";
    } else {
        $result = "The curl action has FAILED! (OUTPUT of curl is: ".$curlresult.")";
    }

//var_dump($curlresult);
echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See, In this code chunk:

```
if ($curlresult == "OK") {
        $result = "The curl action was succeeded! (OUTPUT of curl is: ".$curlresult.")";
    } else {
        $result = "The curl action has FAILED! (OUTPUT of curl is: ".$curlresult.")";
    }
```

it is assumed that `$curlresult` is string, First try `var_dump($curlresult)`  to know what datatype response is returned from this call. May be return type is not string.
Then use the check for that datatype in if condition.